# What iOS function is this image?

Tags: cocoa-touch, ios7

Just wondering if anybody could help me out identifying and creating an iOS option such as this (http://imgur.com/QSfYavr) when a user clicks on a button, it gives the option to use a camera or choose a picture from photo library. I have researched UIIMAGEPICKER however don't think that is what I am after.

I am using latest Xcode + developing for iOS 7 also.

Thanks.

Comment: I think its UIActionSheet

Comment: The menu is a `UIActionSheet`. You would then use a `UIImagePickerController` set the proper source based on the user's selection.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the following code:

```
// Set these delegates in the header file
<UIImagePickerControllerDelegate, UINavigationControllerDelegate,UIActionSheetDelegate>
```

// On Button Action

```
UIActionSheet *actionSheet = [[UIActionSheet alloc] initWithTitle:@"Select Face for Perform Dance step"
                                              delegate:self
                                     cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel"
                                destructiveButtonTitle:nil
                                     otherButtonTitles:@"Camera", @"Select from Library", nil];
    actionSheet.actionSheetStyle = UIActionSheetStyleBlackTranslucent;
    [actionSheet showInView:self.view];
```

// Action sheet delegate

```
#pragma mark -
#pragma mark UIActionSheetDelegate
- (void)actionSheet:(UIActionSheet *)actionSheet clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex
{
    int i = buttonIndex;
    switch(i)
    {
        case 0:
        {
            UIImagePickerController * picker = [[[UIImagePickerController alloc] init] autorelease];
            picker.delegate = self;
            picker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;
            [self presentViewController:picker animated:YES completion:^{}];
        }
            break;
        case 1:
        {
            UIImagePickerController * picker = [[[UIImagePickerController alloc] init] autorelease];
            picker.delegate = self;
            picker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary;
            [self presentViewController:picker animated:YES completion:^{}];
        }
        default:
            // Do Nothing.........
            break;
    }
}
```

At last handle camera and select from gallery actions:

```
#pragma mark -
#pragma - mark Selecting Image from Camera and Library
- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info
{
// Picking Image from Camera/ Library
    [picker dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:^{}];
    self.selectedImage = [info objectForKey:@"UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage"];

    if (!self.selectedImage)
    {
        return;
    }

// Adjusting Image Orientation
    NSData *data = UIImagePNGRepresentation(selectedImage);
    UIImage *tmp = [UIImage imageWithData:data];
    UIImage *fixed = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:tmp.CGImage
                                         scale:selectedImage.scale
                                   orientation:self.selectedImage.imageOrientation];
    self.selectedImage = fixed;

}
```

This code will work on all iOS SDKs 5.x, 6.x, 7.x.
Enjoy. :)

Comment: Hi @Parcs, Thanks for answering my question and providing the code i needed. It successfully works, I have another question regarding multiple imageviews such as in the photo section of this [PictureHere](http://i.imgur.com/DEkoBD0.png) I am unsure on how to keep adding images and setting them to another imageview now, also how would I put the whole view controller into a scroll view?

Comment: You need handle the multiple pictures by your own and manage it on the scrollview.

Answer (score 0):

Its `UIActionSheet` for iOS7, if you updating your app for iOS7 looks for all iOS versions prior to iOS7, here's one already made, you can check it, https://github.com/ianb821/IBActionSheet